# Shell Script To Automate Nginx Blocks

Tags: shell, nginx, reverse-proxy

I'm trying to automate nginx setup through the script

**Command - SECRET_KEY='xxxx' HTTP='$http_update' AMCU_HOST='$host' AMCU_RURI='$redirect_uri' sh ./script.sh domain.com port username**

In the server block file, I want HTTP='$http_update' but it replaces it and just leave blank ''. Same for AMCU_HOST='$host' and AMCU_RURI='$redirect_uri'. Tried without attributes in command but same happens again...leaves '' as script thinks it as $ attr.

## script.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
domain=$1
port=$2
user=$3
block="/etc/nginx/sites-available/$domain"
ssh="/home/$user/.ssh/authorized_keys"

#Create User
echo "▶ Creating User"
sudo useradd $user


#User mkdir
echo "▶ Updating home dir"
sudo mkdir /home/$user

#Create .ssh/authkeys
echo "▶ Updating SSH dir"
cd /home/$user && mkdir .ssh/

#Create the SSH Auth file:
echo "▶ Updating SSH AuthKey"
sudo tee $ssh > /dev/null <<EOF
$SECRET_KEY
EOF

#Create the Nginx server block file:
echo "▶ Updating NGINX Server Block"
sudo tee $block > /dev/null <<EOF
server {

  listen 80;
  server_name $domain;
  return 301 https://$domain$AMCU_RURI;

}

server {
    #Secure HTTP (HTTPS)
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name $domain;
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
    location /500.html {
        root /var/www/html;
        internal;
}
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/$domain/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/$domain/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:$port;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $HTTP;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $AMCU_HOST;
        proxy_cache_bypass $HTTP;
    }

}

EOF

#Link to make it available
echo "▶ Linking Server Blocks"
sudo ln -s $block /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/

#Test configuration and reload if successful
echo "▶ Reloading Server"
sudo nginx -t && sudo service nginx reload
```

Comment: `'$http_update'` is not `"$http_update"` `Updating home dir` - use `useradd -m`. Research `useradd` options. `Updating SSH AuthKey` - Think user ssh stuff should have user permissions.

Comment: That's working as expected. Just the issue is with adding server blocks. It adds as described just replace $http_update $redirect_uri and $host with black space. So I manually have to edit the file again and again.

Comment: `with black space` with "blank" pace? What do you expect for `$http_update`? Is the variable `http_update` set?

Comment: Yes. But as it is a proxy setup. I just want it to be '$http_update' in the conf file

Comment: Then `HTTP='$http_update'` should have worked.

Comment: My question is how to keep the code block and script separate so that they don't mess with each other. I don't want the nginx conf file content to change except the domain and port

Comment: It is working now. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you @KamilCuk , It also helped me!!!